# $\left|\frac{x}{|x|}-\frac{y}{|y|}\right|\leq |x-y|$, for $|x|, |y|\geq 1$?

Tags: inequality

> Let $(V,|\cdot|)$ be a normed space. Let $x, y\in V.$ If $|x|,|y|\geq 1$, then does it follow that
>   $$\left|\frac{x}{|x|}-\frac{y}{|y|}\right|\leq |x-y|\;?$$

Actually I got a hint in form of a picture, but I failed to use it.

[image]

Comment: Hint: Which values do you think $\frac{x}{|x|}$ can have?

Comment: @Did Its norm is 1; Still I cannot see how to apply it to the norm of the difference of the normed vectors.

Comment: What you can prove, IIRC, is $\left|\frac{x}{|x|}-\frac{y}{|y|}\right|\le2|x-y|$

Comment: If  $x, y\in\mathbb R^n$ and $|x-y|$ is the usual euclidean distance between $x$ and $y$, then the inequality is true. The figure hints at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO. Let $V=\mathbb R^2.$ Let $\|(u,v)\|=\max (|u|,|v|).$ Let $x=(1,1)$ and $y=(1/2,3/2).$ The norm of $x/\|x\|-y/\|y\|$ is $2/3.$ But $\|x-y\|=1/2.$

Answer (score 4):

It is false in general. Take e.g. $x=(1 \ \  1)$, $y=(\frac{4}{3}  \ \ \frac{1}{3})$ in the sup norm. Then 
$$ \left|\frac{x}{|x|}-\frac{y}{|y|}\right|= \left|(1 \ \ 1) - ( 1\ \ \frac14)\right| =\frac34 >\left|{x}-{y}\right| =\frac23$$.

On the other hand the following weaker inequality is always true for $|x|,|y|\geq 1$:
$$ \left|\frac{x}{|x|}-\frac{y}{|y|}\right|=
\left|\frac{x|y| -y|y| + y|y| - y|x|}{|x||y|}\right|
\leq \frac{\left|x-y\right|+ \left|\,|x|-|y|\,\right|}{|x|}  \leq 2 |x -y|$$

Answer (score 1):

**A trail:**

As there are only two vectors involved, we may suppose we're in a normed space of dimension $2$.

I conjecture that we may as well suppose we're in $\mathbf C$, and the norm is the modulus, up to an isometry.

In this case, we may as well suppose $\lvert x\rvert=1$, and even that $x=1$. So let $y=r\mathrm e^{i\theta}\enspace(r\ge 1)$. We have to show
$$\lvert r\mathrm e^{i\theta}-1\rvert\ge \lvert\mathrm e^{i\theta}-1 \rvert,$$
i.e.
\begin{align}
(r\mathrm e^{i\theta}-1)(r\mathrm e^{i\theta}+1)&\ge(\mathrm e^{i\theta}-1)(\mathrm e^{i\theta}+1) \\\iff r^2-2r\cos \theta+1&\ge2(1-\cos\theta).
\end{align}
Now, as a function of $r$, $r^2-2r\cos \theta+1$ is increasing for $r\ge 1$ and $\theta\not\equiv 0\mod 2\pi$, so $$ r^2-2r\cos \theta+1\ge 1-2\cos \theta+1=2(1-\cos\theta).$$

Comment: thanks! I am not familiar with the expression "the norm is the modulus, up to an isometry", could you give explain it or send me a (wiki-)links for it(which modulus are u meaning)? I think then I can understand your idea better.

Comment: I mean I identify a dimension 2 (real) vector space with $\mathbf C$. On $\mathbf C$, the modulus of a complex number is a norm (it's actually the Euclidean norm). I made the conjecture that a *normed* dimension $2$ vector space is isometric to  $\mathbf C$. This conjecture rests on the fact that on a finite dimensional vector space, all norms are equivalent. If it is correct, it implies that for the proof, we may as well replace the normed vector space with   $\mathbf C$. Is it clearer?

Comment: Inequalities involving norms do not always hold when changing to a different norm, even in 2 dimensions.  So this answer is incomplete. Equivalence of norms is topological equivalence, not isometric equivalence.

Comment: @user254665: I was not sure, that's why I stated it only as a conjecture (Ideally, it would be simple if…). There's no inner product structure behind a general normed space, unfortunately.

Comment: @user254665 If you can prove that the desired inequality doesn't hold for a particular norm, then you cannot prove it holds in general, can you?

Comment: @egreg. Right. The Q was whether the inequality always holds in all normed spaces, which means for all norms. Even though it does hold for the Euclidean norm.