# Inequality in normed space with normalization

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Is the following true for $\|x\|,\|y\|\geq 1$ and $x,y\in X$, where $X$ is a normed space

$$\left\| \frac{x}{\|x\|}  + \frac{y}{\|y\|} \right\| \leq \| x+y\|.$$

Comment: But then $\|x\|\geq 1$ would not be satisfied.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1960799/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO. Let $X=\mathbb R^2.$ Let $\|(u,v)\|=\max (|u|,|v|).$ Let $x=(1,1)$ and $y=(-1/2,-3/2).$ So $\|x\|=1$ and $\|y\|=3/2.$ We have  $\frac {x}{\|x\|}=x$ and  $\frac {y}{\|y\|}\|=(-1/3,-1).$ So $$\|\frac {x}{\|x\|}+\frac {y}{\|y\|}\|=\|(1,1)+(-1/3,-1)\|=\|(2/3,0)\|=2/3$$ which is greater than$$\|x+y\|=\|(1,1)+(-1/2,-3/2)\|=\|(-1/2,-1/2)\|=1/2.$$